# Checklistbox as processed

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to uncheck a `checkboxlist` item after I process each checked item and I'm not sure how to go about this.

Basic rundown of code

```
string selectedNote="";
foreach (object itemChecked in chkbxSnVisits.CheckedItems)
{
DataRowView drView = itemChecked as DataRowView;
selectedNote = drView["id"].ToString() + " -- " + drView["visit"].ToString();

//do a bunch of stuff
//uncheck itemChecked
}
```

Comment: `(itemChecked as Checkbox).Checked = false;` doesn't work?

Comment: @krillgar Don't use `as` like that. Use a parenthetical cast (`((Checkbox) itemChecked).Checked = false;`).

Comment: @krillgar comes up as: null reference exception - object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: I believe that this question already answered.

Comment: @cdhowie: invalid cast exception - unable to cast system.data.datarowview to type system.windows.forms.checkbox

Comment: Where is the checkbox that you are trying to uncheck? Sorry, I missed the cast the first time.

Comment: within a CheckedListBox, looking for all checked boxes, pulling the data from it, then uncheck them after further processing

Comment: @davek Yes, that exception is more accurate than the NullReferenceException, which is why one should use a parenthetical cast instead of an `as` cast in this context.  (I'm not saying that using a cast at all is the answer, I'm only correcting kirllgar's bad use of the `as`-style cast.)

Comment: @cdhowie thanks. Can't do it like this anyway, at least within the foreach loop. Found out if you uncheck an item from within the loop it throws off the enumerator and won't run.

Answer (score 4):

Its somewhat like,

```
   foreach (int i in chkbxSnVisits.CheckedIndices)
        {
            chkbxSnVisits.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked);
        }
```

Comment: well, just tried this, (had to use "chkbxSnPatientVisits.Items.IndexOf(itemChecked2)" to get the 'i' value since I was using an object) and it won't allow you to proceed. "List that this enumerator is bound to has been modified..." on the foreach loop.

Comment: Maybe you should consider using for loop ; for instance like        for (int i = 0; i < chkbxSnVisits.Items.Count; i++) .. guess there wont be any index problem then

Comment: @davek : you cannot change the "checked" states while you're looping through CheckedItems, since each change you'd make would modify the CheckedItems collection; you first need to finish processing all of them, and only after that you can uncheck them. And for such an action, i endorse the code Rahul posted above.

Answer (score 1):

how I do it is

```
ChechkBoxList chklist;
var chkListCheck = from ListItem item from chklist.Items where item.selected select item;

foreach(ListItem item in chkListCheck ){
item.selected = false;
}
```

I did not knew about the CheckedItem property of the CheckBoxList object, but, to keep this you could just do

```
foreach(ListItem item in chkListCheck.CheckedItems){
item.selected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `async/await` to make your program easier to write and allows easy updating of the UI without all those pesky `Invoke` calls:

Check out this example:

```
async void runCheckedTasks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var button = sender as Button;
  if (button == null) return;

  checkListBox.Enabled = false;
  button.Enabled = false;
  button.Text = "Running...";

  var items = checkListBox.CheckedIndices;
  await DoCheckedTasks(items);

  checkListBox.Enabled = true;
  button.Enabled = true;
  button.Text = "Go!";
}

async Task DoCheckedTasks(CheckedListBox.CheckedIndexCollection indicies)
{
  foreach (int i in indicies)
  {
    // Here you cast to whatever type you are storing in the CheckListBox.
    // I am only using strings like 'First Task', 'Second Task', ...
    var item = checkListBox.Items[i] as string;

    checkListBox.Items[i] = string.Format("Processing {0}...", item);
    checkListBox.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Indeterminate);

    var result = await DoTask(i);

    if(!result)
      checkListBox.Items[i] = string.Format("{0} Failed!", item);
    else
      checkListBox.Items[i] = string.Format("{0} Successful!", item);

    checkListBox.SetItemCheckState(i, CheckState.Unchecked);
  }
}

async Task<bool> DoTask(int index)
{
  var rand = new Random();

  await Task.Delay(3000); // Fake Delay to simulate processing

  var d20 = rand.Next(0, 20) + 1; // Roll a d20, >=10 to pass
  return d20 >= 10;
}
```